# Black/white icon on Xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a problem with displaying an icon in the toolbar.
On Android, it works fine, but on UWP icon is white, and black when you hover it.
Do you know how to fix it?

Android: 
[image]

UWP: 
[image]

My code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="VwDemo.LoginPage"
             Title="Logowanie">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="VwLogo.png" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="10,10,10,0">
            <Label Text="Login" />
            <Entry x:Name="LoginEntry" Placeholder="Login"/>
            <Label Text="Hasło" />
            <Entry x:Name="PasswordEntry" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Hasło" />
            <Button Text="Zaloguj" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" BackgroundColor="#FF3579B4" TextColor="#FFFBF8F8" />
            <Label x:Name="MessageLabel" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Red" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You need to let UWP know the root location of your image see the following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh965322(v=win.10)

Comment: the link that @StuartSmith provided is some old Windows 8 documentation, I would suggest looking at these [xamarin forms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#local-images), which says **Universal Windows Platform (UWP) - Place images in the application's root directory with Build Action: Content.**

Comment: I have the image in the application's root directory with Build Action set to Content.
https://imgur.com/pSaUE05

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem with displaying an icon in the toolbar. On Android, it works fine, but on UWP icon is white, and black when you hover it. Do you know how to fix it?

The problem is that `ToolbarItem` corresponding local control is `AppBarButton`. And `AppBarButton` use [`BitmapIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.bitmapicon) as custom icon.

```
<CommandBar  Background="Transparent" IsOpen="False">
     <AppBarButton  Label="BitmapIcon">
         <AppBarButton.Icon>
             <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///DA.png" />
         </AppBarButton.Icon>
     </AppBarButton>
 </CommandBar>
```

If you pass the image file source to `ToolbarItem`, it will render with `BitmapIcon` in the UWP.  However, there are few limits for BitmapIcon file.

> The file that you use should be a solid image on a transparent background. The bitmap image as retrieved from the UriSource location is expected to be a true bitmap that has transparent pixels and non-transparent pixels. The recommended format is PNG.

For more you could refer this [Remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.bitmapicon#Remarks).

Comment: I have a .png file with transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some digging into this issue and I don't think you will ever get a result as on other platforms. This is because UWP displays toolbar items with a tint - by design. The `AppBarButton`, which is Xamarin.Forms representation of `ToolbarItem` ([Check UpdateToolbarItems method](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/PlatformUWP.cs)) , has the following XAML styles [XAML styles docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299105.aspx). In the `ContentPresenter` part of these styles, you can see that there's a `Foreground` property, which is the tint colour of the toolbar item.

For instance, this UWP code (**not** Xamarin.Forms):

```
TopAppBar = new CommandBar();
(TopAppBar as CommandBar).PrimaryCommands.Add(new AppBarButton()
{
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua),
    Icon = new BitmapIcon()
    {           
        UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png")
    },
    Label = "AAA"
});
```

Will produce below outcome. As you can see the `Foreground` property is responsible for tinting the image

[image]

There's no way - at least not known to me - that you could use `ToolbarItem` (aka `AppBarButton`) to show the image wihtout it being of certain colour/tint. If you still want to achieve such effect you would probably need to create your own version of `CommandBar`.

What you could do though, is to **change the image you're using for that VW logo. Make it transparent** (i.e. remove the blue background from it)